# Getting empty array from getSelection() of Google Charts ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am creating various charts from data using Google Charts. I am using 2 pie charts (chart0 and chart1), which work fine, and when i use chart0.getSelection() and chart1.getSelection() I get a full array returned, and I can open the selected data perfectly into a dataTable. But when I use getSelection() on the ColumnChart, selection is an empty array with no data inside it. I cannot figure out why nothing is being returned.

```
var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2Div'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'select', selectHandler2);
function selectHandler2() {
    var selection = chart2.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
     doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks fine here though http://jsfiddle.net/h7mSQ/316/ . Maybe the error is somewhere else. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console either. My only thought was that ColumnCharts are formatted differently than PieCharts, but in the documentation, .getSelection() is documented to work with ColumnChart the same way.

Also i wouldnt think it would matter about formatting because it would still return data inside the array?

Comment: Presence of PieCharts in the same page should not change anything. Can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I am using a webservice for my company to retrieve the data, so im not too sure how i would construct the chart in jsfiddle

Comment: use the jsfiddle I created and edit it for your situation. Use fake data.

Comment: Okay i think I found out the problem. I am constructing an array of data by grabbing it in JSON and then pushing the formatted data into the array. I constructed it differently than with the pie charts.

Comment: [["Flag","Obsolete","Sole Source","Two or More","Unknown","Proprietary","Logistics",{"role":"annotation"}],["2015",980,955,593,91,5,416,""],["2016",1000,955,593,91,5,396,""],["2017",1042,1026,519,91,5,357,""],["2018",1133,1196,274,91,5,341,""],["2019",1352,1054,191,91,5,347,""]

I know i did something wrong with the formatting and labeling of the columns/rows. This is the array that the columnChart is built from.
"Flag" is the label for the following strings like: Obsolete, sole source ,etc.

And then they are broken up by year.

Comment: Actually, it turns out the array populates upon select, but ONLY when i double click the part of the column. In the pie chart it happens upon single click. Why do i have to double-click for the select to populate array?

Comment: that's really weird.